# Add multiple body in email using python

Tags: python

I am trying to add multiple messages to email body but some how not able to do so.

```
#!/usr/intel/pkgs/python/2.7.2/bin/python
import sys 
import argparse
import os
import time
import commands
import subprocess
import mmap
import sys 
import argparse
import os.path
import smtplib



from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart()

monty_python = "monty_python.txt"

if(os.path.getsize(monty_python) > 0) is True:
  text = "\n\n Cool !! some info found"
  part1 = MIMEText(text,'plain')
  with open(monty_python , 'r') as input_data:
  thestring = input_data.read()
  montystring = thestring[thestring.find('---------Monty Python-----'):]
  e_mailthis = montystring[montystring.find('\n')+1:]
  monty_log = MIMEText(e_mailthis,'plain')  
  print monty_log

else:
  text = "No info found"
  part1 = MIMEText(text,'plain')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(monty_log)

print ("msg is %s")%(msg)

me  = "my_email"
you = "receiptant's email"

msg['Subject'] = 'Monty Python info' 
msg['From'] = "me"
msg['To'] = "you"

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

### text file monty_python.txt

---------Monty Python-----
line1
line2
line3

with above code i am able to get email message but content of monty_python.txt files which i am trying to parse comes as an attachement but i am trying to get is as a body of email.

Any suggestions/input ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, send email from xxx@gmail.com to yyy@gmail.com

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_email(content):

    msg = MIMEText(content)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Title'
    msg['From'] = "xxx@gmail.com"
    msg['To'] = "yyy@gmail.com"

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.login("xxx@gmail.com", "password")
    s.sendmail("xxx@gmail.com", "yyy@gmail.com", msg.as_string())
    s.close()
```